# sql-dump failing when run as cron

Tags: drush, cron

I have a shell script that executes `drush sql-dump`, compresses the result and then sends it to a backup server.

It works fine when run from the command line as root but it is failing silently and dispatching an empty file when run as part of a scheduled cron job.

This script has worked previously for me on another website as a cronjob and so I am somewhat confused what would be wrong now.

I work with Drupal 8.3.1 and Drush Version 8.1.11.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add `-v` for verbose messages. Probably you're out of memory or you need to increase PHP time execution for drush.

Comment: Why would the resource requirements be different for cron compared to doing it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much frustration I have resolved the issue and will post the answer in case it is of use.

Cron seems to not always have access to the same PATH information as when a normal user - or even root - runs a drush command in a command line.

The solution came from comment [#7 in this drush thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/715480).

You need the path to drush. You can find this with the command:

```
which drush
```

In my case it was `/usr/local/bin/drush`

Then add the path info to the top of the shell script.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

And then it worked perfectly.

Additionally, it appears if your local mail is not set up correctly cron discards output from scripts which is why the `drush: command not found` error was not turning up in logs. To make sure you get logs from cron configure it for local mail. [See this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog).

Comment: This finally fixed things for me, **even though** I had already thought to spell out */usr/local/bin/drush* and */usr/bin/gzip* in full in my bash script. (slightly odd setup, backing up on a Mac Mini being used as a production server…)